# Trying to restart UIBezierPath on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I'm trying to restart a UIBezierPath with the click of a button.

I tried to play around with the opacity.

Basically, I have 3 arrows that get drawn in an animation, and then if the user clicks on the animate button, I want them to re-animate.

This is what I have for drawing the arrows:

```
func animateArrow(firstPoint: CGPoint, endPoint:CGPoint) {

    let arrow = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(firstPoint, endPoint: endPoint, tailWidth: 7.5, headWidth: 15, headLength: 15)

    let arrowPath = CAShapeLayer()

    arrowPath.path = arrow.CGPath
    arrowPath.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    arrowPath.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    let opacityAnim = CABasicAnimation()
    opacityAnim.keyPath = "opacity"
    opacityAnim.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    opacityAnim.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.7)
    opacityAnim.duration = 1.0

    arrowPath.addAnimation(opacityAnim, forKey: "opacity")
    arrowPath.opacity = 0.7

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(arrowPath)

}
```

This is the animation part:

```
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.colorize(labelArray[b.toInt()!], color:self.cyan)
            self.animateArrow(pointArray[a.toInt()!], endPoint: pointArray[b.toInt()!])
        })
        dispatch_after(time2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.colorize(labelArray[c.toInt()!], color:self.cyan)
            self.animateArrow(pointArray[b.toInt()!], endPoint: pointArray[c.toInt()!])
        })
        dispatch_after(time3, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.colorize(labelArray[d.toInt()!], color:self.red)
            self.animateArrow(pointArray[c.toInt()!], endPoint: pointArray[d.toInt()!])
            self.animateButton.enabled = true
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all the sublayers you have added by removing the `sublayer` from view inside button click event.

Please make sure that you draw the paths in a separate overlay view and not the underlying view that contains the button and other UI. If you use the code below in the main view, the UIView layers will also get removed.

```
func clicked (button:UIButton) {
    for layer in viewToClear.layer.sublayers as [CALayer]
    {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```